# Convert BLDC motor thrust in grams ($\rm g$) to Newton ($\rm N$)

Tags: newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion, aircraft, lift

I am making a quadcopter with takeoff weight equal to 2 Kg. Using thrust to weight ratio of 3:1 the required thrust per motor is 1500g. (No experimental thrust has been obtained for thrust.)

Now I am trying to calculate the vertical velocity (climb rate) which can be achieved with this thrust by the drone. When I tried to convert this gram thrust to Newton I came across to concepts:

1. That the acceleration provided by using thrust to weight ratio is same as gravitational acceleration i.e thrust/weight = m1a/m2g = 3.
2. The $g$ in propeller thrust is gram-force which can be convert by
   multipling 1000/9.81

Which of this concepts is correct or am I missing something in here. And how can I use that thrust in grams to calculate the climb rate?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gravity exerts a force of about 19.6 N on a 2 kg object. With a thrust to weight ratio of 3:1 the thrust would be 58.8 N. With (58.8 – 19.6) = (2)a, that could give an upward acceleration of 19.6 m/s/s.

Comment: Is it ok to use the thrust to weight ratio on force? In every site I have visited used the ratio on the acceleration or the mass. This is the first time I see using the ratio on force.

Comment: Thrust and weight are both forces. By the way, the maximum upward velocity will depend on the friction with the air.

Comment: Sorry I meant mass not weight. I used the thrust to weight ratio on mass like 2kg:6Kg.

Comment: Then I used it to find motor with 1500g thrust force, since ever motor specify the thrust in grams. Now how can I convert that grams to force, just multiply it with gravitational  acceleration as you did?

Comment: The weight of 1.5 kg of mass is about (1.5 kg)(9.8 N/kg) = 14.7 Newtons of force. Or, the weight of  one gram of mass is about (1 gram)(980 dynes/gram) = 980 dynes of force. (1 N = 1E5 dynes)